# Optimising background-attachment: fixed

Tags: css, background-image

I'm working on a project that involves 2 instances of background-attachment: fixed. Ideally I'd like a third in there but I've turned it off for now as it's just a bit too much.

Also I have these background images set to background-size:cover

```
.banner {
background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
height: 100vh;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed; }
```

&

```
.testbackground {
background-image: url('../img/forest1.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -1;
/* will-change: transform */
/* transform: translateZ(0) */ }
```

I know this question has been asked before and I've been digging around a lot trying to find an answer but:

Is there a way to optimise performance when using this property? The issue is that the page becomes a bit jittery when scrolling up and down.

I've used the will-change: transform trick as outlined here: https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property

I've also used transform: translateZ(0) which from my understanding is a hacked way to create the same rendering trick that will-change does.

I've noticed a slight bit of difference with both of these. But ultimately the browser is not running silky smooth as I'd like it to be. Is this just a perennial issue that comes with using the fixed property? Or is there a way to make things nice and smooth?

Thanks,

Edit: Interestingly when I resize my browser down to a small size (500px width) the page becomes smoother. So I'm wondering if the file sizes have something to do with it.. perhaps using something like Optimizilla to compress the image sizes will make a difference?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or some sort of link?